# Pascal Boolean return value?

Tags: pascal

I'm currently working on an exercise of testing Boolean value from user input, as being presented below:

```
function ReadBoolean(prompt: String): Boolean;
var
    choice: String;
    exit: boolean;
begin
    repeat
    begin
        WriteLn(prompt);
        ReadLn(choice);
        case choice of
        'yes','y','t','true': exit := true;
        'no','n','f','false': exit := false;
        else
            WriteLn('Not a boolean input. Enter again: ');
        end;
    end;
    until exit=true or exit=false;
    result := exit;
end;
```

It is expected to keep looping asking for value until it receives the input from specified string, however at my first attempt when I try to input 'fred' the boolean variable is automatically assigned as TRUE and exit the function.

Any helps would be very appreciated.

Comment: `until exit=true or exit=false;` doesn't this mean the loop end no matter if `exit` is `true` or `false`?

Comment: yeah indeed, is there anyway to stop the loop from exiting before it meets those cases above, cos personally I think boolean always have a default assigned value...

Comment: `until choice='yes' or choice='y' or choice='t' or choice='true' or choice='no' or choice='n' or choice='f' or choice='false';` should work although it could be too lengthy.

Comment: Alternatively, you can loop indefinitely (`while true`) and break it when one case is met.

Comment: thanks will give it a try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my understanding, you only want the loop to end when user enters some specific strings.

It can be achieved by modifying the `until` condition like this:

```
choice='yes' or choice='y' or choice='t' or choice='true' or choice='no' or choice='n' or choice='f' or choice='false'
```

Or alternatively, create an indefinite loop and break it when user enters an expected string:

```
while true do
  ...
  'yes','y','t','true':
    begin
      exit := true;
      break;
    end;
  'no','n','f','false':
    begin
      exit := false;
      break;
    end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: using while is actually better, I've just added some 'break' to exit the loop after each case otherwise it will keep looping no matter the string is matched or not, and now the program works perfectly as expected. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop terminates when `exit=true or exit=false`.  As `exit` can only ever be one of those two values, it will always meet that condition, so it will never run your loop.

But also, consider explicitly setting the value of `exit := false` before starting your loop.

Comment: Personally I think boolean value always have assigned default value, but is there anyway to have exit unassigned before the loop ends? Cos the thing I want it to do here is it must meet those cases above, otherwise it should keep looping.

Comment: Variables may have a default value, but only if the compiler states that.  I suspect that your Pascal compiler would assign false to the variable, but to be honest I didn't understand your question and was just offering general advice.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking here is "nullable" boolean thing (value is true, value is false, value is not provided). As far as I know it's not implemented in any Pascal dialect. So that, you have to split your indication into two separate flags: a) is there any well-formed input provided by user; b) is the input is recognized as true or false

```
function ReadBoolean(prompt: String): Boolean;
var
    choice: String;
    exit: boolean;
    recognized: boolean; { this is our termination flag }
begin
    recognized := false; { we place it to false initially as no user input recognized yet }
    repeat
    begin
        WriteLn(prompt);
        ReadLn(choice);
        case choice of
        'yes','y','t','true': begin exit := true; recognized := true; end; { we mark it as recognized }
        'no','n','f','false': begin exit := false; recognized := true; end; { we mark it as recognized }
        else
            WriteLn('Not a boolean input. Enter again: ');
        end;
    end;
    until not recognized; { we keep asking for user input until known input provided }
    result := exit;
end;
```

Comment: I actually have solved the problem with above recommendation, but I will try your solution as well, much appreciated :)

Comment: @HoangNguyen, indeed you have more than one option to implement the scenario. Nullable approach would help much if you need, let say, integer input, or string input where empty string is acceptable answer too, etc.